# Inserting DOM elements using content script in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to make an extension for twitter and I'm stuck at inserting the div block (Kinda like btn) in this section
[image: Twitter bar where I want to add the save btn]

**Manifest.json**

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Twitter Saver",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Twitter Saver| Save tweets.",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "https://*.twitter.com/*"],
    "icons": {
        "128": "img/icon-app-128.png",
        "256": "img/icon-app-128@2x.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "html": ["save-dropdown.html"],
            "js": ["js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js", "js/content.js"],
            "matches": ["https://*.twitter.com/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Content.js**

```js
$(
        "<div>",{
            class: "css-1dbjc4n r-18u37iz r-1h0z5md",
            text: "HELLO WORLD"
        }
    ).appendTo(".css-1dbjc4n.r-1ta3fxp.r-18u37iz.r-1wtj0ep.r-1s2bzr4.r-1mdbhws");
```

I've looked into few things like [MutationObserver](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers)
but here I got error as parameter is not a node

```js
let react_root = $("#react-root");
let callback = function(changeList, observer) => {
         console.log(changeList);
}
const observer = new MutationObserver();
observer.observe(callback, {childList: true});
```

Twitter removes the previous posts as scrolling down adding new ones and adds the previous ones removing new ones when scrolling back to top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Twitter, MutationObserver is the way to go, and for how to use it, I prefer [this Mozilla guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

To get is working correctly, note the syntax: here in registering the MutationObserver, it says watch the entire body and descendants, and call function `appendCustomNode` when change occurs.

```js
// Step 1. Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
// const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
// Step 2. Start observing the target node for configured mutations
// observer.observe(targetNode, config);

const observer = new MutationObserver(appendCustomNode); 
observer.observe(document.body, {subtree: true, childList: true});
```

Next step is to define this function `appendCustomNode`.

In planning how to append nodes to the cards, it is necessary to take into consideration that you will see the same node possibly multiple times, which requires having a strategy to append the custom element only once. Picking some sufficiently random value, then tagging all previously seen nodes with that value, will help accomplish this. Here is an example:

```js
const customTag = `tag-${Date.now()}` // your choice of a valid & unique value

function appendCustomNode(){

  // find all timeline cards, their tag name is article
  const cards = document.getElementsByTagName('article');

  // check each card
  for (let n = 0; n < cards.length; n++) {

     const card = cards[n];

     // check that cards is new / has not been seen before
     if (!card.hasAttribute(customTag)) { 

       addButton(card);

       // mark the card as "processed" by adding the custom tag
       card.setAttribute(customTag, true);
     }
  }
}
```

Lastly implement the logic to append the button you want to add to the card. Here card attribute represents the DOM node of one timeline item.

```js
function addButton(card){

   const myButton = document.createElement('div');
   myButton.innerText = 'hello world';

   // select the div of action buttons
   // or wherever you want to insert your custom node 
   // SEE NOTE BELOW
   const target = card.querySelector('....?....')

   // append/prepend/insertAdjacentHTML the button here
   target.append(myButton);
}
```

I will leave this last part open for a few reasons: when deciding how to find the buttons row in the card, if using classes as a selector, the implementation breaks if the classes change, which is out of your control. This is always a challenge when extending 3rd party web apps. I suggest trying to find a more reliable selector (which is why earlier I used tag name article to select cards). Secondly the buttons/card structure changes periodically, so that is another point to consider: where do you want to insert this custom node. Lastly this approach does not require jQuery.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I've been trying to do this but due to lack of exp I couldn't. Is there any way I can open a popup from my html file by clicking on that added element?
Popup like in page drop down menu with few select options

Comment: Yes it is possible. If the HTML is simple you can have it as a string variable, then create a div (programmatically) like in the answer, and then set the innerHTML to be the HTML string. If it is more complicated then you can [try something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69762595/4054683) or iframe to do it.